# Using mv command

Tags: cygwin

I downloaded a file containing pictures in my downloads and I am trying to move it to another folder but it gives the error

I wrote the command `mv guernica.jpg ~ /artworks/painting`

> ```
> DEV HENRY@DESKTOP-U ~
> $ mkdir artworks
>
> DEV HENRY@DESKTOP-U ~
> $ cd artworks
>
> DEV HENRY@DESKTOP-U ~/artworks
> $ mkdir paintings
>
> DEV HENRY@DESKTOP-U ~/artworks
> $ cd paintings
>
> DEV HENRY@DESKTOP-U ~/artworks/paintings
> $ mv guernica.jpg ~ /artworks/paintings
> mv: target '/artworks/paintings' is not a directory
> ```

Comment: It's just a typo. Read the error message closely :)

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the space between ~ and /